# Fill the value for a column in a group which is having null with non null value in same column in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a  result set grouped like `City` and `WeekID`.

I have `null` for the `Date` and `SKUCode` when it is Other City. So now I want to bring the `Date` and `SKUCode` for the record which is same date & SKU Code like in the group.

INput:

| WeekID | Date | City | SKUCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020_1 | NULL | Other | NULL |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | NYC | CN03 |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | Dallas | CN03 |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | Miami | CN03 |
| 2020_10 | NULL | Other | NULL |
| 2018_10 | 2020-03-05 | NYC | CN03 |
| 2018_10 | 2020-03-05 | Dallas | CN03 |
| 2018_10 | 2020-03-05 | Miami | CN03 |

Expected Output:

| WeekID | Date | City | SKUCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | Other | CN03 |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | NYC | CN03 |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | Dallas | CN03 |
| 2020_1 | 2020-01-01 | Miami | CN03 |
| 2020_10 | 2020-03-05 | Other | CN03 |
| 2020_10 | 2020-03-05 | NYC | CN03 |
| 2020_10 | 2020-03-05 | Dallas | CN03 |
| 2020_10 | 2020-03-05 | Miami | CN03 |

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: i tried using first_value &  lag () function

Answer (score 2):

You can impute a value using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(date, max(date) over (partition by weekid)) as imputed_weekid,
       coalesce(date, max(SKUCode) over (partition by weekid)) as imputed_SKUCode
from t;
```

Comment: this query will be resulting same values for all date & SKUCOde.. 
there are many SKUCOde & dates